# Azure Data Factory - Trigger Pipeline Manually Externally

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I currently have a Data Pipeline within ADF that pulls data from multiple REST APIs, transforms the data and stores it in an Azure SQL Database and from there is imported into Microsoft Excel through Power Query. At the moment this is scheduled to trigger once a day. At the beginning of the month, I find that I'm needing to login to Azure and manually trigger this pipeline multiple times a day as that data needs to be refreshed more often (financial data).

Is it possible to create a script, or even better, allow Microsoft Excel to manually trigger the pipeline to run at the more busier times of the month? In a perfect world, I'd love to be able to have a Query & Connection which I can click Refresh that will execute the pipeline and pull the latest data, however, I don't believe that's possible?

My next thought would be to create a Python script which I can run using a Macro/VBA from Excel. Any other ideas is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually run your pipeline by using one of the following methods:

•   .NET SDK

•   Azure PowerShell module

•   REST API

•   Python SDK

Unfortunately, there is no way to trigger ADF pipeline from Microsoft Excel.

For more information follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers)